# unsorted list of bullets in a docstring note

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

It is possible to have a "note box" in a Python docstring using [the `..` syntax](https://sublime-and-sphinx-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes_warnings.html).

```
.. note::
   This is note text.
   With more than one line.
```

However, it seems like it is not possible to add an unsorted list:

```
.. note::
   This is a list:
   * item 1
   * item 2
```

Am I missing something? Is this even possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a blank line between the text and the list:

```
.. note::
   This is a list:

   * item 1
   * item 2
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something silly! Thanks buddy!